# Why does my app force closes on using getarguments().getstring(key) in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have the following  fragments.
1. addtaskfragment extends Fragment   2. mycontacts  extends Fragment
I am at present doing the following.
I have some textfields and button in addtaskfragment. On clicking the button I can go to mycontacts fragment. I am passing a value from mycontacts to addtaskfragment. The problem is that my app is giving force closes. My codes are as below. Please tell me step by step what to do?

addtaskfragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addtasknew, container,
            false);
       final String strtext=getArguments().getString("k");
 addcontacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

     Fragment fr;
      fr=new mycontacts();
      FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
      android.app.FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putString("temp","1");
    //  args.putString("taskname",datepick.getText().toString());
    //  Log.i("temp from long click",""+temp);
      fr.setArguments(args);
      ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fr);

               ft.commit();
}
  });
     }
```

mycontacts

```
          Fragment fr;
          fr=new addtaskfragment();
          FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
          android.app.FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
          Bundle args = new Bundle();
          args.putString("CID", cid);
          args.putString("k", cid);

          Log.i("cid",""+args);
          fr.setArguments(args);
          ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fr);

                   ft.commit();
```

error logs

```
  E/AndroidRuntime(4507): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  E/AndroidRuntime(4507): java.lang.NullPointerException
  E/AndroidRuntime(4507):   at com.example.taskmanager.addtaskfragment.onCreateView(addtaskfragment.java:62)
  E/AndroidRuntime(4507):   at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
  E/AndroidRuntime(4507):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
  E/AndroidRuntime(4507):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
  E/AndroidRuntime(4507):   at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
  E/AndroidRuntime(4507):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
  E/AndroidRuntime(4507):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
  E/AndroidRuntime(4507):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
  E/AndroidRuntime(4507):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  E/AndroidRuntime(4507):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  E/AndroidRuntime(4507):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
  E/AndroidRuntime(4507):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  E/AndroidRuntime(4507):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  E/AndroidRuntime(4507):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
  E/AndroidRuntime(4507):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
  E/AndroidRuntime(4507):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: remove  `final String strtext=getArguments().getString("k");` from your `OnCreteView(......)` from `addtaskfragment`

Comment: I need to get the value from mycontacts fragment to addtaskfragment. So I can't remove it

Comment: where is your `Button` in your `addtaskfragment` fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your arguments aren't null

Comment: My arguments are not null.I have use toast to verify that.

Comment: Then simply you mapped the line number by mistake and your "addContact" is the one that's null :), because i don't see any initialization for it in the above code

Comment: getarguments() was returning null. thanx

Answer (score 0):

Your `addcontacts` you attempt to invoke `setOnClickListener()` on is `null`.